# Scrolling issue in SeeTest Automation using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, seetest

I am facing Scrolling issue in `SeeTest Automation` for Android automation using Mobile Webdriver + Selenium .

I have tried `JScriptExcecutor` , Scroll methods also but i was not able to scroll so anyone can help me regarding this ?

Comment: Share the webpage where you want to scroll.

Comment: My application is having 15 fields and after filling 5th field the keyboard is overlapping the 6th field so i need to scroll for adding data in to the 6th field

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll in android device using screen dimensions, find the below function,

```
public void scroll() throws IOException {
              try {
                Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
                System.out.println("Size of Window= " +dimensions);
                int Startpoint = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5);
                System.out.println("Size of scrollStart= " +Startpoint );
                int scrollEnd = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2);
                System.out.println("Size of cscrollEnd= " + scrollEnd);             
                driver.swipe(0, Startpoint,0,scrollEnd,1000);           

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }    
          }
```

add this to ur code and simply use scroll(); in ur test case

Comment: Getting error as "The method swipe(int, int, int, int, int) is undefined for the type 
 MobileWebDriver"

I am using Seetest MobileWebDriver sir